# Django and 2 questions

Tags: django

This is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from depot.models import Subject, Student

# Create your models here.
class Credit(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    first_level_questions = models.IntegerField(default=8)
    second_level_questions = models.IntegerField(default=8)
    third_level_questions = models.IntegerField(default=4)

class Question(models.Model):
    credit = models.ForeignKey(Credit)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    level_choice = (
        (1, u'1'),
        (2, u'2'),
        (3, u'3'),
    )
    level = models.IntegerField(choices=level_choice)
    a = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    c = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    d = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    right_answer_choices = (
        (1, u'a'),
        (2, u'b'),
        (3, u'c'),
        (4, u'd'),
    )
    right_answer = models.IntegerField(choices=right_answer_choices, blank=True)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    right = models.BooleanField(default=None)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.answer

class Mark(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    credit  = models.ForeignKey(Credit)
    total = models.IntegerField()
```

This is my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from credits.models import Credit, Question

class QuestionInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Question
    extra = 0

class CreditAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['subject', 'number']
    inlines = [QuestionInline,]


admin.site.register(Credit, CreditAdmin)
```

I solve my first problem. Thank you.
My second problem:
I want to have a method in my mark model.
You know like:

```
def total_mark(self):
    return Answer.objects.filter(student=self.student, right=True).count()
```

But what about credit? I need marks of exact student and exact credit.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not clear on your second question. If you have separate questions or more questions you should create separate questions instead so they're easier to find. You should also post how you solved your first question in case others come looking with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, I think this has to do with the fact that a `ChoiceField` has the value `''` (empty string) if nothing is selected. This is a problem for the two choice fields you are creating, because they want integers but they can't convert `''` to an integer. I assume this error comes up when you submit the form? Have you selected a `right_answer` when you submit? I would try removing the `blank=True` from that field - after all, every question should have a right answer!

---

As for your second question, you probably want something like this in your view:

```
# given a student object s
correct_answers = Answer.objects.filter(student=s, right=True).count()
# now you can save the mark how you want
```

Comment: Teachers can create questions without variants and thats why without right answers)

Comment: Well, I think that's going to be a problem for the `right_answer` `IntegerField`. You need to override the default value for the `ChoiceForm` that gets created in the admin interface so it doesn't try to parse `''` when it's blank. Another option would be to add another choice for "no correct answer" (e.g. `(0,u'none')`) in your `right_answer_choices`.

Comment: I already solve it thanks. Look at my question. I modify it to explain what I want in the second problem.